# CFile equivalent in C#.net

Tags: c#

I want to create a binary file in C#.net - the file should contain some header information
and binary data.

The CFile provides the provision to create a same file in the text mode as well as binary mode.

In C# .net a TextWriter and BinaryFormatter to do this. Is it possible to use a single stream class?

Note : Header information should be plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx):

```
using (var stream = File.Create("foo.dat"))
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Personname : aaaaaaa ; Personage : xxxxx .... and the binary information should come so if use the binarywriter the strings will be added with special characters which is not required , I need a plain text header

Comment: @Raghav55, you could use the `Write(char[])` method of the writer to write text characters to the file.